# Reduce the size of variables declaration using a loop with Pine Script

Tags: loops, variables, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to know if it would be possible to use a loop to reduce the number of lines for the variables declaration.The list is as follow (from 0 to 24)

```
var long0 = false
takeprofitlong0 = 0.0
takeprofitlong0 := takeprofitlong0[1]
stoplosslong0 = 0.0
stoplosslong0 := stoplosslong0[1]
var long1 = false
takeprofitlong1 = 0.0
takeprofitlong1 := takeprofitlong1[1]
stoplosslong1 = 0.0
stoplosslong1 := stoplosslong1[1]
```

I guess I would have to use arrays and for i = 0 to 24 but I cannot find how to do it.

I've tried using loop and arrays but it seems to not work when using the ":=".
Also I don't really understand the array function in Pine Script.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because each variable has a unique name.

For the specific piece of code you shared, you can use the `var` keyword.

> var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.

Below code just makes sure that `takeprofitlong0`'s value is kept consistent between each iteration. However, that is old syntax.
takeprofitlong0 = 0.0
takeprofitlong0 := takeprofitlong0[1]

However, that is old syntax. You can do the same as below:

```
var float takeprofitlong0 = 0.0
```

Unless you specifally do `takeprofitlong0 := xx` later in the code, its value won't change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you for letting me know about the new syntax, it will make the strategy a bit lighter!